# Composition of entire functions is identity, then functions are linear

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

A question from a previous qualifying exam at my university reads:

"Suppose that f and g are entire functions such that $f \circ g(x) = x$
when $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ and $g$ are linear functions."

One can conclude that the composition of $f$ and $g$ is the identity on all of $\mathbb{C}$, by the uniqueness principle. I know how to solve the problem if one assumes that $f$ is injective. However, there are examples of functions that have a right inverse but are not injective. However, entire functions have many properties, so is there a way of showing $f$ must be injective from the information above, or should I approach the problem differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Injectivity of $f:$ Note that $$(g\circ f) (g(z)) = g[(f\circ g)(z)] = g(z).$$ Thus $g\circ f$ is the identity on $g(\mathbb C).$ Since $g(\mathbb C)$ is a set with limit point, the identity principle shows $g\circ f$ is the identity on $\mathbb C.$ This proves $f$ is injective.

Comment: I learned from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337154/how-to-show-image-of-a-non-constant-entire-function-is-dense-in-mathbbc) that one can also use the Liouville's theorem to show the denseness of $g(\mathbb C)$ (+1).

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Right, that step is used in proving CW. Actually the density of $g(\mathbb C)$ is not needed here. I edited my answer.

Comment: Once you conclude $f$ is injective, the remainder of the proof is not overly difficult. If $f$ is not a polynomial, then its power series expansion at 0 must have an infinite number of terms. So $f$ will have an essential singularity at $\infty$. Then $f$ will not be injective by Picard's big theorem. If $f$ is a polynomial of degree 2 or higher, then it would not be injective by the fundamental theorem of algebra. So $f$ must be linear.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f\circ g$ is the identity, $g$ is injective. An injective entire function is a linear polynomial.

Indeed, by the great Picard theorem, if it has an essential singularity at infinity, it is not injective. So it must have a pole at infinity (not a removable singularity, or it would be constant). [An entire function that has a pole at infinity is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1079463/62967).

If it is not a linear polynomial it is not injective: indeed, it cannot have distinct roots, so it is of the form $a(z-b)^n$, with $a\ne0$. The equation $a(z-b)^n=a$ has $n$ distinct solutions, so we conclude $n=1$.

Thus $g(z)=a(z-b)$, so $f(z)=a^{-1}z+b$.

Comment: You can use Casorati-Weierstrass to see an injective entire function cannot have an essential singularity at infinity

Comment: @zhw. “The theorem is considerably strengthened by Picard's great theorem,...”

Comment: just pointing out the problem at hand has an elementary solution.